# ElasticProperty in elastic search 2.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-1.0.0

I use following Elastic properties in elastic search 1.0

```
[ElasticProperty(Name = "description", Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Type = FieldType.String, Analyzer = "custom_lowercase_analyzer", SearchAnalyzer = "search_analyser")]
    public string description { get; set; }
```

How can we use these properties in elasticsearch 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/mapping.html) for more details,

```
[Text(Name = "first_name", Analyzer = "custom_lowercase_analyzer", SearchAnalyzer = "search_analyser")]
public string description { get; set; }
```

Index = FieldIndexOption.Analyzed is removed instead we have Index=true or false 
Index is true by default so you don't need to provide it.